# file_exists() not working

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.15 and am trying to use a simple `file_exists()` php function. But i cant get it to work.

when i just return the image url, the image shows. but when i use `file_exists()` it returns `$img2`

function in my model

```
 public function brandPageImage($make = false) {
        $urlstr = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/brand-pages/make/';
        $img = $urlstr.trim(strtolower($make)).'-976x365.jpg';
        $img2 = $urlstr.'default-976x365.jpg';

        clearstatcache();

        if (file_exists($img)) return $img;

        return $img2;
 }
```

if i return `$img` directly it works!

```
 public function brandPageImage($make = false) {
            $urlstr = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/brand-pages/make/';
            return $img = $urlstr.trim(strtolower($make)).'-976x365.jpg';
     }
```

this is the url it generates

`/dev/frontend/www/images/brand-pages/make/lol-976x365.jpg`

can someone help me, don't see what i'm doing wrong here. I'm running XAMMP on OSX
Thanks

Comment: does the file really exists?

Comment: `/dev`? Sure? This is the *nix devices subsystem. It would be very weird to have JPEGs stored there.

Comment: @YeahBoy yes it does, like i said, when i return `$img` on line 3, the image shows.

Comment: Where do you use that `$img` string? In an `<img>` tag?

Comment: Hmmm... What @BartFriederichs means is that this would be a very bad choice for a folder to store the image... Like storing your regular documents in `C:\Windows\System32\` would be a bad choice on Windows machines

Comment: @BartFriederichs running XAMPP on my OSX

Comment: Your image is not, by any chance, called `LOL-976x365.jpg` or something is it?

Comment: @RichardBernards the full url would be `http://localhost/dev/frontend/www/images/brand-pages/make/lol-976x365.jpg` just the folder name in my `htdocs`

Comment: Could you go to the path (in a console) where that file is located and type `pwd` ? That is the path you need to feed to `file_exists`.

Comment: @CD001 nope, all lowercase

Comment: Running in safe mode? `/dev/` may well be a blocked directory if you are and in which case `is_file()` will return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use getPathOfAlias instead of baseUrl,Because Yii::app()->request->baseUrl returns base URL, not document root path.

```
  if (file_exists(YiiBase::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'images/brand-pages/make/‌​
                 lol-976x365.jpg')) 
 { 
      // do what you want to do
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with since it need the path and not the url where the image resides

```
 public function brandPageImage($make = false) {
        $urlstr = dirname(Yii::app()->request->scriptFile).'/images/brand-pages/make/';
        $img = $urlstr.trim(strtolower($make)).'-976x365.jpg';
        $img2 = $urlstr.'default-976x365.jpg';

        clearstatcache();

        if (file_exists($img)) return $img;

        return $img2;
 }
```

Comment: still don't work url your code generates is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev/frontend/www/images/brand-pages/make/lol-976x365.jpg`

Comment: once again can you check if the image is available pls, atleast with the url directly